# Variable on Toggle Jquery, Help hide show button

Tags: javascript, jquery

This simple code works, but i want to ask about this`$("p").toggle();`
If i change the `"p"` for example to `"p1"` and i also change the `<p>This is a paragraph.</p>` to  `<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>`, it doesn't work and i dont know why. Can anyone tell me is it possible to change the variable to something else, also it's not variable and i am wrong ? Or i just can't do it and it has to be always`$("p").toggle();`?

```
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>`

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$("p").toggle();
});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you try with #p1? as it's id not element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to change `<p>This is a paragraph.</p>` to `<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>` then you have to use `#p1` in your selector, so it looks like `$("#p1")`

`#` represents an `id` so if you `id` is `p1` then you have to use `#p1`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#p1").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<p id="p1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<button>Toggle between hide() and show()</button>
```

Comment: yeap it Works thank you a lot i will also accept your answer in 10 min :)

Comment: @Markoskarpodinis No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 0):

$("p") will select elements by html tag name

In your case you have to select elements by id 
$("#p1")